# "Reputation & Moderation" page still says "Stack Exchange the company"

Tags: bug, help-center

The "Reputation & Moderation" page on any site (`/help/site-moderators`) still refers to the company behind Stack Exchange as Stack Exchange and not Stack Overflow.

> Moderators act as a liaison between the community and Stack Exchange the company.

Seeing as how the name change was recent, I'm not surprised this hasn't been caught yet, and I'm sure there are other instances of this around somewhere.